# Get source from the_post_thumbnail

Tags: multisite, post-thumbnails

I'm struggling because I'm using the "Sitewide Tags"-Plugin to grab all posts in a network to the main blog. Now I want to embed the post images to the main blog and the only function you're able to use for that is: `the_post_thumbnail ();`

But I'm using a grid layout for which I just need the url of the image (src). For that I cant't find the solution and would be very thankful for some help.

Best regards,

Philipp

Comment: I am not sure how is that plugin influencing the process there. That function calls [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_post_thumbnail/) internally and looking at its source should give you the idea on how data is retrieved and formed.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that as well but without success...

Comment: `get_the_post_thumbnail` is correct. If you can't get that working, post the problematic code please.

Comment: Thanks again. The problem is, that the plugin doesn't store the image in the post meta itself - As far as I understood. 
As you can read here (http://wpmututorials.com/plugins/post-thumbnails-for-sitewide-tags/) it's also just possible to grab the "thumbnail" size. What is finde for me at the moment. 
As `the_post_thumbnail();` is the only way (It is, I'm sure), I have to find a way to extract the src from it... :)

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[Get post thumbnail url with multisite](http://regid.biz/kak-poluchit-adres-kartinki-s-uchetom-multisajta-v-wordpress/)

If you want to display materials on multisite function without switch_blog_id, then output the image material standard features wordpress fail. For this, I wrote this little function as a turnkey solution is nowhere found.

```
function multisite_thumb_url($pid, $bid){ //$pid - post id, $bid - blog id 
if(isset($pid) && $pid>0){
    if(isset($bid) && $bid>0){
        global $wpdb;
        $curr_blog_id=get_current_blog_id();
        $wpdb->set_blog_id( $bid );
        $post_thumbnail_id = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' AND post_id = {$pid}" );
        $post_thumbnail_metadata = $post_thumbnail_id ? maybe_unserialize( $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attachment_metadata' AND post_id = {$post_thumbnail_id}" ) ) : NULL;
        if ( ! $post_thumbnail_metadata ){
            return false;
        }else{  
            if($bid==1){
                $default_post_thumbnail_url = get_blog_option( $bid, 'siteurl' ).'/wp-content/uploads/'.$post_thumbnail_metadata[ 'file' ];
            }else{
                $default_post_thumbnail_url = get_blog_option( $bid, 'siteurl' ).'/wp-content/uploads/sites/'.$bid.'/'.$post_thumbnail_metadata[ 'file' ];          
            }
            return $default_post_thumbnail_url;
        }
        $wpdb->set_blog_id( $curr_blog_id );
    }else{
        return wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($pid) );
    }
}else{
    return wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. Please add some further description to the code example, thanks.